# Unrecognized option "user" under "doctrine.dbal.connections.default"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a Symfony application and it works perfectly on remote, but on localhost, I can't start server. It throws an error `Unrecognized option "user" under "doctrine.dbal.connections.default"` when executing `php bin/console server:start`. I'm using symfony 3.0.0, and doctrine 2.5.2.

The thing is that if I remove that user option, it tries to connect with the database with the default user: root. But of course, I don't want to connect using root, I want to connect with my real db user.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

I'm running windows 10 with last wamp version on local, and debian 8 in remote.

Comment: Check the indentation of your config.yml / config_*.yml , is it correct ?

Comment: It's correctly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answer myself. The whole problem was that I refactored at some point from `Users` to `User`, or from `User` from `Users` or something like that. And my IDE refactored that wrong (or I wasn't cautious enough) and broke something.

The thing is that if I write `User` instead of  `user`, it works. This is just a workaround because I didn't fix the real problem, because I still don't know which fragment of code was modified with the refactor. But as this project was just an exercise for an online course ant it won't be in production ever, I think it will remain like this until I find where the real problem was.